# Tabularx and multicolumn (containing an X cell and a regular cell)

Tags: tabularx, multicolumn

There have been many questions about `tabularx` and `\multicolumn` but I haven't found an answer to this one.

One can use `X` columns for two reasons: the first is to have equal-width paragraph columns, in formats like `|X|X|X|`; but there is also another reason: to have a table of full text width containing a paragraph column and other non-paragraph columns of variable width, without tedious calculations about the exact width of the paragraph column (which would be necessary in a `p` type column). This would be a format like `|l|l|X|l|`.

This is what I'm using, but at some point I need to merge this `X` column with the neighboring one, which is a regular `l` column of unknown width:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|l|X|}
A word&Another one&This sentence is set in the remaining space of the first line\\
Something&\multicolumn{2}{X|}{And here I would like to occupy the space of columns 2 and 3 again for a long sentence that has to be broken into a paragraph}
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In the screen capture I have placed a red frame around the space I would like to occupy.

Reading other answers I noticed that I can change the width of the multicolumn by using the following code in the format: `>{\hsize=1.33\hsize}X`. But this means that for every table and column combination I will have to fiddle around to find the exact value of the factor of `\hsize`.

What I need is a way to obtain it automatically, without the necessity to run the document a dozen of times until I get the correct value of the `\hsize` coefficient. I.e., a paragraph column that will have the width of the `X` column plus the one of the neighboring `l` column (plus the intercolumn width).

Is there a way to get that?

(Notice that contrarily to other questions on stack exchange, this is not `X`-cell arithmetic, where the multicolumn replaces *n* `X` columns so that its width is simply *n* times the width of the `X` column. Here the width of the `l` column is variable and not related to the width of the `X` column in any way.)

Comment: some things you can't have....  In most (or some) real cases you can fix the middle column say `|l|wl{2cm}|X|`  then your multcol is easy `\multicolumn{2}{X|}{\hsize=\dimexpr\hsize+2cm+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax ....}` or if you know the longest entry in the middle column measure that first instead of guessing 2cm

Answer (score 1):

Based on David's suggestion, here is a solution to the problem. The only compromise is that you need to provide the contents of the widest cell of the column in each newly defined `\multicolumn` command. But this is by far easier than fiddling with coefficient values (and not getting it right in the end…).

Here is my code:

```
\newlength{\yhwidth}
\def\yhmulticolumn#1#2#3#4{\multicolumn{#2}{#3}{\settowidth{\yhwidth}{#1}\hsize=\dimexpr\hsize+\yhwidth+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax #4}}

\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|l|X|}
A word&Another one&This sentence is set in the remaining space of the first line\\
Something&\yhmulticolumn{Another one}{2}{X|}{And here I would like to occupy the space of columns 2 and 3 again for a long sentence that has to be broken into a paragraph}
\end{tabularx}
```

and the result:

[image]

Thanks David!

(Now if anyone has a solution without the need of giving the largest cell's contents, don't hesitate to share it! After all, `longtable` does such largest cell calculations to obtain tables over several pages, so it should be possible to do it…)